# Is it possible to open Photoshop and an extension using custom url protocol?

Tags: javascript, photoshop, custom-url, custom-url-protocol

I would like to create a button on a web page that will open Photoshop with an extension.

I managed to open Photoshop via a button through this site:
https://medium.com/swlh/custom-protocol-handling-how-to-8ac41ff651eb

But I have not found how to open a Photoshop extension at the same time.

Here is my CustomProtocol.html file :

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="CustomProtocol.js"></script>

<body>
    Hey, I'm a web page !
    <a href="my-prot://">Run Photoshop</a>
</body>
```

Here's where the extensions are : C:\Program Files\Common Files\Adobe\CEP\extensions

This is the kind of extension I'm talking about :

[image]